# How to implement CryptoJS.AES.decrypt in Go

Tags: javascript, go, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have a 'simple' AES decryption with a given key using CryptoJS in Javascript

```js
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

let encrypted = 'U2FsdGVkX19dGrnVQb3BYZ9SWtQBCt2XZDeWFBEfWoi3qnSHg26aQnADUKjTDtSgpPUDzXc59XrIBsTZp9IRg4dYy9Lo0/GjSVn8qlINhE8NJXozQvUNPJSs6nvWSiivCsh9KHGsWFEusMeTefM9V2hKRpQHnFp5VHDLPgGImjHXOQO71eO4qFoQ3ESqUdnDO94nlTjcJU8AP+GabRMjHP08OVz87uyV4SfvT7AZhAYuOPOumHbJaV5nHz2ouqBZgXR3OK07AUk6V+Faz43BT3Qd2+xGLyz8C+teekmudVhmGlnzvMK/VUs0bNDUttdVVnkz/VbXVOj++07uhDsJoMKzZQYTNLkIl9HnuXDmhKOrLSYs2EYpNrH9T/2ZP3nwqJaI7bbLBCfCpNFGNLY4jyNou4Bl5GEK6sxg0zraUCZTgvfuuvBpKWFcFhPvYf8eJGoI3dOWTRWyRnS6e4j3bg==';
let key = 'KBlgcIOrad7EYpiz9LNNTMSg98QoqSVK';

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);

let data = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(data);
```

I were trying to decrypt that data in Go (Golang) but failed. I have no knowledge about AES, here my code so far

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    encrypted := "U2FsdGVkX19dGrnVQb3BYZ9SWtQBCt2XZDeWFBEfWoi3qnSHg26aQnADUKjTDtSgpPUDzXc59XrIBsTZp9IRg4dYy9Lo0/GjSVn8qlINhE8NJXozQvUNPJSs6nvWSiivCsh9KHGsWFEusMeTefM9V2hKRpQHnFp5VHDLPgGImjHXOQO71eO4qFoQ3ESqUdnDO94nlTjcJU8AP+GabRMjHP08OVz87uyV4SfvT7AZhAYuOPOumHbJaV5nHz2ouqBZgXR3OK07AUk6V+Faz43BT3Qd2+xGLyz8C+teekmudVhmGlnzvMK/VUs0bNDUttdVVnkz/VbXVOj++07uhDsJoMKzZQYTNLkIl9HnuXDmhKOrLSYs2EYpNrH9T/2ZP3nwqJaI7bbLBCfCpNFGNLY4jyNou4Bl5GEK6sxg0zraUCZTgvfuuvBpKWFcFhPvYf8eJGoI3dOWTRWyRnS6e4j3bg=="
    key := "KBlgcIOrad7EYpiz9LNNTMSg98QoqSVK"

    e, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encrypted)
    k := []byte(key)

    dst, err := decryptAES(e, k)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(dst))
}

func decryptAES(ciphertext []byte, key []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("ciphertext is too short")
    }

    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]

    stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    plaintext := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
    stream.XORKeyStream(plaintext, ciphertext)

    return plaintext, nil
}
```

And the result: �9�������ff��ܱ�������jTY:���SV�PZ*LDw%�z��0���&���j@'��_H��0+����b�8�b}�;Yڸ�d���0�^P얿L�aC�3�2�*m��d׺�h�
-׸��%Z(0��c�v�r�:�=�>}���b��n������g�lu}�������&�3�.�%|M���fxdGW27z�D��J���"(�[D�+<��n�z�4:�����
��iZs�ix��G�$��.= �3J��5{"g��#z ���Z�#���@���Xs��#�ZR;���VI������ ��w�X/�bp�r
��

Quick try: https://goplay.tools/snippet/QooAajJ4ky0

Please help me decrypt that data using Go or fix my code. Thank u <3

Comment: CryptoJS uses the CBC mode by default and - if the key material is passed as string - a key derivation function (`EVP_BytesToKey()`). On the Go side, neither the key derivation function nor the correct mode (CFB instead) is used. The decryption must therefore fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Topaco**'s clearely mentioned in the comment,

According to `CryptoJS` [Documentation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding), The default mode is `CBC`. So your cipher text is encrypted in `CBC` mode.

But in your `go` code, You have used `CFB` mode by using `cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)` to decrypt the cipher text which is obviously not the correct mode.

Instead of [NewCFBDecrypter](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#NewCFBDecrypter) you have to use [NewCBCDecrypter](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/cipher#NewCBCDecrypter)

I could successfully decrypt using https://github.com/Luzifer/go-openssl package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Luzifer/go-openssl"
)

func main() {
    data := "U2FsdGVkX19dGrnVQb3BYZ9SWtQBCt2XZDeWFBEfWoi3qnSHg26aQnADUKjTDtSgpPUDzXc59XrIBsTZp9IRg4dYy9Lo0/GjSVn8qlINhE8NJXozQvUNPJSs6nvWSiivCsh9KHGsWFEusMeTefM9V2hKRpQHnFp5VHDLPgGImjHXOQO71eO4qFoQ3ESqUdnDO94nlTjcJU8AP+GabRMjHP08OVz87uyV4SfvT7AZhAYuOPOumHbJaV5nHz2ouqBZgXR3OK07AUk6V+Faz43BT3Qd2+xGLyz8C+teekmudVhmGlnzvMK/VUs0bNDUttdVVnkz/VbXVOj++07uhDsJoMKzZQYTNLkIl9HnuXDmhKOrLSYs2EYpNrH9T/2ZP3nwqJaI7bbLBCfCpNFGNLY4jyNou4Bl5GEK6sxg0zraUCZTgvfuuvBpKWFcFhPvYf8eJGoI3dOWTRWyRnS6e4j3bg=="
    secret := "KBlgcIOrad7EYpiz9LNNTMSg98QoqSVK"

    o := openssl.New()

    dec, err := o.DecryptBytes(secret, []byte(data))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("An error occurred: %s\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Decrypted text: %s\n", string(dec))
}
```

**Output**

```
Decrypted text: [{"file":"https://eno.tendoloads.com/_v6/71f87b4028d27b3ba749bd2029f3248245618a740ca81a9a9863f257784436f85c939482f4d306945639b935dc612f232173cae4f207297dea8798f69741cdadcf03986938ae645355b02ac49101bd99d26dbcacac3e6ab00b678324a21474728d09a70cb4b5086fbc36943efb9f1695c522b23382b639d8f473c8ce9a528151/master.m3u8","type":"hls"}]
```

**OR** If you want to use `CFB` in `CryptoJS`, Then you have to specify the mode explicitly.

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
});
```

Comment: according to @Topaco and your comments, I've implemented two ways with the CFBDecrypter but still hasn't worked. Please tell me where I was wrong
https://goplay.tools/snippet/IclwPQt6J-h
https://goplay.tools/snippet/vKO75FYqo6l

Comment: i mean CBCDecrypter

Comment: OMG you're such a genius. thank you so much <3

Comment: Glad it solved the issue, If you find this helpful, Please accept the answer.

Comment: I accepted, thank you again